# Custom Component in Laravel Spark

Tags: laravel, apache-spark, vue.js

I try to add my custom component to my Laravel Spark instance and always get the error:

> Property or method "obj" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render..

It all works fine if i only bind a data value (ex. "testkey") without a loop...but if i add the for loop i receive this error...so my code:

app.js (spark)

```
require('spark-bootstrap');
require('./components/bootstrap');

//my new Component
import OmcListObjects from './components/modules/omc/objectlist.vue';
Vue.component('omc-objectlist', OmcListObjects);

var app = new Vue({
    mixins: [require('spark')]
});
```

my Component (objectlist.vue)

```
<template>
    <div :for="(obj in objlist)" class="property-entry card col- col-md-4 shadow-sm">
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default  {
        data () {
            return {
                objlist: [{title: 'test1'}, {title: 'test2'}],
                testkey: 'testval'
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean by `:for` the `v-for` directive, directives are always prefixed by `v-` like `v-for` one in which the compiler can recognize the `obj` variable as an temporary element used in the loop, but if you set `:for` which is recognized as a prop bound to a data or another property.

Comment: Thanks that worked!....i had to wrap the loop in a div and then it worked with v-for.